# Removing upper margin in ConstraintLayout with bottom navigation

Tags: android, layout, constraints

I have created Bottom Navigation Activity in Android Studio. Now I'm adapting all layouts to my needs but I have a severe problem with removing that margin between nav_host_fragment and it's parent which is Constraint Layout. This causes the layout of all fragments to be displayed with an unwanted offset or a margin.

https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/6421823700_1611991870.png

The layout is defined as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:paddingTop` in your constraint layout is the cause of your issue, remove it and you must be good to go.

Try the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <!-- child view remains the same -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a different approach to this, if you don't have this paddingTop in the root view, you probably have some

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the root view (where your nav host resides). Remove it and add it to the fragment you're injecting in NavHostFragment.